# how to find draggable product related values name, price

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have tried drag and drop using jquery UI , i have updated this into fiddle

**JSFIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/GPBUn/

**JQUERY CODE:**

```
//draggable start
            $(function () {

        // jQuery UI Draggable
                $(".products-grid .item a img").draggable({

                    // brings the item back to its place when dragging is over
                    revert:true,

                    // once the dragging starts, we decrease the opactiy of other items
                    // Appending a class as we do that with CSS
                    drag:function () {
                        $(this).addClass("active");
                        $(this).closest(".products-grid .item a img").addClass("active");
                    //  $('.hover').css("display","none");


                    },

                    // removing the CSS classes once dragging is over.
                    stop:function () {
                        $(this).removeClass("active").closest(".products-grid .item a img").removeClass("active");
                    }
                });

                // jQuery Ui Droppable
                $(".basket").droppable({

                    // The class that will be appended to the to-be-dropped-element (basket)
                    activeClass:"active",

                    // The class that will be appended once we are hovering the to-be-dropped-element (basket)
                    hoverClass:"hover",

                    // The acceptance of the item once it touches the to-be-dropped-element basket
                    // For different values http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance
                    tolerance:"touch",
                    drop:function (event, ui) {

                        var basket = $(this),
                                move = ui.draggable,
                                itemId = basket.find("ul li[data-id='" + move.attr("data-id") + "']");
                                 var param = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');

                        // To increase the value by +1 if the same item is already in the basket
                        if (itemId.html() != null) {
                            itemId.find("input").val(parseInt(itemId.find("input").val()) + 1);
                            var price=move.find(".itemprices").html();

                        }
                        else {
                            // Add the dragged item to the basket

                            //alert(p);
                            addBasket(basket, move);

                            // Updating the quantity by +1" rather than adding it to the basket
                            move.find("input").val(parseInt(move.find("input").val()) + 1);
                        }
                    }
                });

                // This function runs onc ean item is added to the basket
                //+ '<span class="sno">1</span>'
                function addBasket(basket, move) {
                        var val=move.find(".product-name").html();
                        //alert(val);
                    basket.find("ul").append('<li data-id="' + move.attr("data-id") + '">'                          
                            + '<span class="name">' + move.find(".product-name").html() + '</span>'
                            + '<span class="price">' + move.find(".itemprices").html() + '</span>'
                            + '<input class="count" value="1" type="text" id="count">'
                            + '<button class="total">'+ (move.find(".itemprices").html())*($(".count").val())+'</button>'
                            + '<button class="delete">&#10005;</button>');

                }

                $("#count").on('change', function(){
                var v=$("#count").val();
                //  alert(v);
                });
                // The function that is triggered once delete button is pressed
                $(".basket ul li button.delete").live("click", function () {
                    $(this).closest("li").remove();
                });

            });
            //draggable ends
```

here drag and drop functionality is working fine , but how do i get the product title and price ,any help ?

Comment: `var price=$(ui.draggable).closest('.products-grid').find('.itemPrices');` within your `drop()` would give you the price of the dropped item. similarly , you can get the product title as well.

Answer (score 0):

For price =>

```
 $(".itemprices").text();
```

For title =>

```
   $(".product-name").prop('title');
```

//NEW CODE
See if you have multiple products ,Assign separate ID to every Product DIV (you already have class assigned to it).Then use # instead of '.' (DOT) . So use

```
var idStored=$(this).attr('id');
idStored.text();

idStored.text().prop('title');
```

And then Call these Manipulation on Hover of the div ,Or onClick

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: 
In your `addBasket(basket, move)` function add the following line:

```
var currentLIelement = $(move).parents('li');
```

So, `currentLIelement` will be your parent `<li>` element of dragged element. 
Now, to get the **title** you need to call this:

```
$(currentLIelement).find('.product-name').prop('title')
```

And to get the **price** you need to call this:

```
$(currentLIelement).find('.itemprices').text()
```

**NOTE:** In your code I found `live()` method - [As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.](https://api.jquery.com/live/)